# Set different values on a certain column when unnesting repeated field

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following table:

```
| Id |         Services          | Value | Type |
-------------------------------------------------
|  1 |  ['One', 'Two', 'Three']  |  30   |   A  |
|  2 |      ['One', 'Two']       |  20   |   A  |
|  3 |         ['One']           |  40   |   B  |
```

I need a query that unnest the field `Services` and keep `Value` only on the first element of the unnest (it doesn't really matter which element gets the value, but I need it only once).

The result would be like this:

```
| Id | Services | Value | Type |
--------------------------------
|  1 |  'One'   |  30   |   A  |
|  1 |  'Two'   |   0   |   A  |
|  1 | 'Three'  |   0   |   A  |
|  2 |  'One'   |  20   |   A  |
|  2 |  'Two'   |   0   |   A  |
|  3 |  'One'   |  40   |   B  |
```

I am using Standard SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to use `WITH OFFSET` clause, see the query below

```sql
WITH Test AS (
    SELECT 1 Id, ['One', 'Two', 'Three'] Services, 30 Value, 'A' Type UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, ['One', 'Two'], 20, 'A' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, ['One'], 40, 'B'
) SELECT Id, Service, IF(offset = 0, Value, 0) Value, Type
  FROM Test, UNNEST(Services) Service WITH OFFSET AS offset
```

You've got
[image]

Comment: That worked exactly as I was asking. Thanks for your time